# Camera intent with GPS enabled

Tags: android, gps, camera, android-intent

Is there a way to launch the camera app via an intent with GPS turned on, so that the returned photo is geo-tagged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible with a camera-intent.

Whether you use the API to Geo-Tag it (since you need to get the current LatLon) or you take the picture using an intent and then edit the EXIF-header.

To add the GeoTag, you can use the [`setGpsLatitude()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setGpsLatitude%28double%29) and [`setGpsLongitude()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setGpsLongitude%28double%29)-methods

Comment: To add more details: check [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), there are only two parameters you can pass to intent (EXTRA_OUTPUT and EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY). You can check how location capture is implemented in gingerbread [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Camera.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/camera/Camera.java;h=66b180517098aa8e41cc7e184058813462253127;hb=4b478c9940ad3e79f1c99ad70b2aa7b4643b3946)